# Weird CSS behavior when using visibility: hidden. Is that defined in a spec?

Tags: html, css, visibility

I'm using the latest Chrome 35.

My understanding from the CSS Keyword visibility is that `visibility: hidden` simply doesn't render the element including all child elements while keeping it in the document flow.

Now while I debugged an existing application I stumbled over the following weird behavior. The parent element (parEl) is set to `visibility: hidden` and has two child elements (childA, childB). The element childA has it's visibility set to visible. From what I thought up until today was, that nothing should be visible, yet childA is actually displaying.

I don't know, is that a browser bug or actually intended behavior and if it is, where is this specified?

**JSFiddle here:** http://jsfiddle.net/7Yev6/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although this behavior seems counter-intuitive, it is in fact the intended behavior. This is stated in the [propdef for `visibility`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#propdef-visibility):

> **hidden**
>   The generated box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is drawn), but still affects layout. Furthermore, descendants of the element will be visible if they have 'visibility: visible'.

The behavior you might expect where descendants are hidden comes from the fact that they inherit the `visibility: hidden` value from their container by default when the property is not specified directly.

Note that `visibility` and `opacity` differ in that `opacity` is not inherited, but instead the effect `opacity` has on an element also applies to its descendants and cannot be reversed (which means if you had `opacity: 0` on the parent, `opacity: 1` will not cause its children to be fully opaque).

Comment: Can't quite believe I've never noticed this.

Comment: Same goes for me. Doing this for years now, yet I've never noticed this until I found this bug in the application. It seems so basic, yet I wouldn't think I could find a useful purpose for it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification between visibility and opacity and their differing inheritance... I have gotten stuck with visibility many times in the past and this clears up those issues.

Answer (score 3):

The property is inherited by child elements by default, but doesn't apply to them.

See http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/visibility